# Finding first even number in a list with algorithm complexity better than linear

Tags: python, algorithm, list, complexity-theory

I have list with first odd elements and then even, so odd elements come first in a list and then there are even elements. For example:

```
list = [5,99,3,7,111,13,4,24,4,8]
```

So the even elements start after odd elements with number 4. Doing this with linear complexity would be simple but it has to have better complexity so binary search comes to mind but I don't know how to implement it for this case. Thanks for help.

Comment: Use binary search to determine at what index it starts swapping. You can see the even elements as "too large", and the odd ones as "too small".

Comment: If question still applies to C++, there is [`std::partition_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point) which does the job. (with similar example).

Comment: @ManojBanik binary search is O(log n)

Comment: @Mitchel Paulin, My bad, I was intended to write O(log n), Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

Since the values are already organized, just take the middle of the collection (array, list) and check wether is it an even or odd value.

Is it even? Then the first even values is in the first half of the collection and you can discard the second half or it is the current one.

Is it odd? Then the first even value havent come yet, discard the first half, keep the second one as your new collection and keep doing this until you find it.

Some visual guide:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/binary-search-in-python-visual-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

Rayner Fernandez got this right in the other answer: binary search gets this done inO(log n) time. The reason this works is because the input list is effectively sorted in descending order of *parity*. Because all you care about is parity, this is good enough for binary search; your input is equivalent to one with all 0s and 1s as far as binary search is concerned. You can think of this as running binary search looking for 1/2, and returning the last index binary search looked at before it failed to find its target.

In summary: check the value in the middle of the list. If it's even, you know the last odd element is to the left; otherwise, if it's odd, you know that the last odd element is this element or to its right. Then, repeat this same procedure on the smallest subarray in which you've determined the last odd element exists.

Answer (score 0):

We know the criterion of when binary search works. As the array has the 000..0111..1 property, we can easily use binary search here.

In binary search there are two boundaries, lets say them low and high where low = first index and high = last index of the array. And in each iterator we find the midium element  from low to hight by using (low + high) / 2. So when we find a midium element to check, what can we do here? We can check if it is even or not.If the number is odd, we can ignore the elements from low to that midium index as all the elements from low to midium index will be odd. In that case we can change our lower boundary low to midium + 1. Now if the midium index is even, then that midium index can be our answer but the answer can be between low to midium - 1 indices too. So we will decrease our higher boundary to midium - 1.

Thus we can get the minimum index with even number.

code:

```
ans = len(list)
low = 0, high = len(list) - 1
while low <= high:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if list[mid] % 2:
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        ans = mid
        high = mid - 1

# here ans is the index of the first even number
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) comes with very simple, but well tested [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/bisect.py).

Try modifying that code by replacing the `a[mid] < x` test with an even/odd test `a[mid] % 2 == 1`.

This should help you solve the problem but without us actually writing the code for you.

Good luck :-)